# When to use the Micro Gum in Chulip?

Tags: ps2, chulip

A couple walkthroughs are saying to go to the hole in the fence in the back alley and chew the gum at 5pm when the chime sounds. However, the only chime I hear is at 6pm and neither time seems to work right for chewing the gum (I'm just going to the inventory and selecting "eat", which just causes me to eat the gum with no further effects). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it--as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPRyud9xdWs#t=626), it works if you eat the gum between 5:05 and 5:10. I'm still not sure about the "chime" you're supposed to listen to, but 5pm is the right time, and you do have to eat (rather than use) the gum.